# Websocket programSubscribe and signatureSubscribe crash intermittent (WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING))

Tags: web3.js, websocket, node.js

I'm having intermittent issues with a Node.js app where websockets listening to program or signature changes completely stop working and not recover. I'm using @solana/web3.js `onProgramAccountChange`/`programSubscribe` and `signatureSubscribe`. Anyone experienced this as well and has a solution?

It is happening on different OS (ubuntu + centos), different hosts, and also with different RPC services.

This is the call when starting the program:
`connection.onProgramAccountChange(<program address>, parseAccounts, 'confirmed', filter)`

It is flooding below messages, and then after a few minutes the application crashes.

```
programSubscribe error for argument [
   '<program address>',
   {
     encoding: 'base64',
     commitment: 'confirmed',
     filters: [ [Object], [Object] ]
   }
 ] WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)
```

```
signatureSubscribe error for argument [
  '3ruw2YxenzUkcMNkvG9LTzbGMi2ewcdPu9nx89cByQxF59MBA7zT52TzqruHo4JnEC5EbvE7JQAMYWjwFpBDZxaS',
  { commitment: 'confirmed' }
] WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)
```

**EDIT** Seeing also this TODO call here, might just hit an errored state which cannot be recovered from:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/cfdf3f345dced3b7041856f6e51ceef3dcef6ce2/src/connection.ts#L6006

Comment: Which exact version of `web3.js` are you using? There was a major fix added in version 1.70.2. https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/29130

Comment: I reproduced this issue on a devnet endpoint with solana/web3js version 1.73.0

Comment: A WebSocket related fix was made in 1.73.2. Please try that! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/releases/tag/v1.73.2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s more of a bug report rather than a question-and-answer opportunity.