# Websocket readyState 2

Tags: web3.js, javascript, websocket

I've built a small program that monitors for new transactions on an address and then uses signatureSubscribe to watch for transaction confirmation. After running the program for a while, it will randomly and unpredictably start flooding the console with errors:

```
Tried to call a JSON-RPC method `signatureSubscribe` but the socket was not `CONNECTING` or `OPEN` (`readyState` was 2)
signatureSubscribe error for argument [
  'transaction_id_goes_here',
  { commitment: 'confirmed' }
]
```

I cannot find a clear solution to this problem; I did find a mention of something similar but it's old and closed, as the problem was said to be solved: [Websocket programSubscribe and signatureSubscribe crash intermittent (WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING))](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5113/websocket-programsubscribe-and-signaturesubscribe-crash-intermittent-websocket)

Comment: I am using v1.87.6 of web3.js

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more of a bug report than a question-and-answer opportunity. Please make sure that you're running at least v7.5.1 of `rpc-websockets` (https://github.com/elpheria/rpc-websockets/pull/138) and if you are, file an issue on the `@solana/web3.js` Github.